# Javascript works in FF and IE .. but Chrome says "cannot call method of null"!

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

The code that contains the error is:

```
var Slide = new Class({
    initialize: function(triggers, panels) {
        this.triggers = $(triggers).getElements('a[rel=content1-1]');
        this.panels = $(panels).getElements('ul[class=rel-content1-1]');
        this.active = -1;
        this.toggle();
    }, ...
})
```

This is called from later in the same file:

```
function activateSliders() {
    var slide_1 = new Slide('aCol', 'content');
    var slide_2 = new SlideTwo('content', 'content2', 'content2-hider');
}
window.onload = activateSliders();
```

Why does Chrome -- and only Chrome -- calculate `$(triggers)` as NULL?

Comment: `window.onload = activateSliders();` should be `window.onload = activateSliders;` because you're setting window.onload to the actual function, not the results of the function.

Comment: Are you using some sort of framework? Mootools perhaps?

Comment: Ah, good point @jake33. And I'm assuming that jQuery is being used here, though I could be very, very wrong. That's what I get for being too hasty.

Comment: There is no `Class` object or `$` function built into Javascript, so what library are you using?

Comment: I'm going to guess that it's not jQuery because jQuery doesn't have a "getElements" function and when `initialize` is being called via `new Slide(...)`, it doesn't specify the elements via the xpath syntax that jQuery uses (jQuery would use "#aCol" or ".aCol" instead of just "aCol").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, IE and FF tend to be sporadically generous with letting jQuery code work nicely *without* it being encapsulated within a `$(document).ready(` block. Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    activateSliders();
});
```

Comment: This works.  And, the first comment on the question (from jake33) gave the specific reason why my code wasn't working.  Thanks to both of you!